# oracle sql pl/sql how to subtract dates/workweeks

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

I have two columns as below.

I calculated difference column by using ww1-ww2. But i didn't get correct results on first 2 rows. How should i modify my calculation?

I tried to_date(ww1)-to_date(ww2) but it didnt work :(

```
ww1     ww2     difference
201401  201347  54
201401  201346  55
201405  201404  1
201406  201405  1
201408  201405  3
201409  201408  1
201409  201406  3
201409  201407  2
201410  201409  1
201420  201419  1
201425  201424  1
201427  201426  1
201428  201426  2
```

==================update 1=========

ww1 and ww2 have dates in YYYYWW format where YYYY is year and WW is work week

my difference column should show workweek difference. So 6 on row 1 considering 52 weeks in any year.

============update2==================

i looked at answers below and I feel that this is what i need. This is how I will program in Excel and I would prefer if anyone could give SQL solution.

if(substring(ww1,4)==substring(ww2,4),ww1-ww2,(substring(ww1,4)-substring(ww2,4))*53+substring(ww1,5,6)-substring(ww2,5,6))

where substring(ww1,4) gives me first 4 characters of a ww1 and substring(ww1,5,6) give me 5th and 6th character of ww1

I need to do this way as each year i have 53 weeks. I would appreciate any help with above formula

Comment: I don't understand . . . 201347 + 54 = 201401.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: 201347 is not a number it is year 2013 and workweek 47. I am expecting 6 over here

Comment: I think you need to extract last two digits, convert them to_number, then substract

Comment: @Hawk you are correct. Would it be possible to answer update2?

Comment: @user2543622 I've answered based on your second update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your second update, my understanding is that you are trying the calculate the weeks difference between two dates. One of the possible solutions (given every year is 53 weeks):

```
SELECT ( CASE 
           WHEN ( To_number(Substr(ww1, 0, 4)) = To_number(Substr(ww2, 0, 4)) ) 
         THEN 
           To_number(Substr(ww1, -2)) - To_number(Substr(ww2, -2)) 
           WHEN ( To_number(Substr(ww1, 0, 4)) <> To_number(Substr(ww2, 0, 4)) ) 
         THEN ( 
           ( 
         To_number(Substr(ww1, 0, 4) - To_number(Substr(ww2, 0, 4))) * 53 ) + 
           To_number (Substr(ww1, -2)) ) - To_number(Substr(ww2, -2))
         END ) AS diff 
FROM   weeks;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da60a/17/0)  for testing

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to treat these as dates, in the YYYYWW format, then you need to convert back to a date.  It would be nice to do this:

```
select to_date(ww1, 'YYYYWW') - to_date(ww2, 'YYYYWW')
```

But, it is not allowed.  So:

```
select ( (to_date(substr(ww1, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 7 * to_number(substr(ww1, 5, 2)) ) -
         (to_date(substr(ww2, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 7 * to_number(substr(ww2, 5, 2))
       ) as DiffInDays
```

If you want the diff in weeks, then divide by 7.

As a note:  you should store the week as the date of the beginning (or end) of the week.  It makes such manipulations *much* easier.

EDIT:

For this to work across multiple years without fractions you need to be sure that the weeks start on the same date.  Here is one method:

```
select ( (next_day(to_date(substr(ww1, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Sun') + 7 * to_number(substr(ww1, 5, 2)) ) -
         (next_day(to_date(substr(ww2, 4) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Sun') + 7 * to_number(substr(ww2, 5, 2))
       ) as DiffInDays
```

I do fear that this might have an off-by-one error in some years.  Frankly, I (nor anyone else on the web) knows your definition of the nth week in a given year.  You need to apply your definition to get the first day of the week and then do the subtraction as days.

Comment: if i divide by 7, would it be a division with remainder 0? Could i get 5.6 or 6.1 or would it be always an integer?

Comment: @user2543622 . . . You know, within one year, it would always be an integer.  For dates that span multiple years, it is *probably* not an integer.  Solving that problem is a bit harder.  You can fix this by changing the first `to_date()` to `next_date(to_date(. . .), XX)` where XX is based on your definition of the week.

Comment: would it be possible to update your solution? My year is always going to have 53 weeks

Comment: @user2543622 . . . How can your year always have 52 weeks?  Years are not built that way; they have 52 weeks plus one day.  Often, companies have calendars that have 52 weeks for about 5 out of 7 years, and 53 weeks for the remaining 2 or so years.

Comment: sorry, It should be 53 weeks. It is company's calender ...they always have 53 weeks